# React Native pass and get params in two class components

Tags: react-native, class, navigation

I am getting this error and I can't find out why. I am looking for the answer since hours but I simply cant find it. Would be really happy if someone can help.
I click on the card in try to navigate to the detail page put it simply doesnt passes the parameter:
[image]

[image]

And when I try to call it in this class I am always getting this error:

[image]

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: do you have a single navigation, or have nested navigations.

Comment: Which react navigation version you are using ?

Comment: I have two a AuthStack and a StackNavigator and the version is 4.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That's how you can get params in class components:**

```
 render(props) {

const {item} = this.props.route.params;

 return() 
      }
```

Comment: You are not passing props in the render method of your second screen. Pass props in the render method and let me know if you still facing that error.

Comment: muhammaaaad I need your hellllp

Comment: On your Second screen, you are not getting the params right, You have to accept params like this in your second screen:                                                                                    
 const {item} = this.props.route.params;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first class:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator, Button, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Card from '../../common/Card/Card';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements'
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import storage from "@react-native-firebase/storage";

class CardListScreen extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.firestoreRef = firestore().collection('restaurants');
        this.state = {
          isLoading: true,
          userArr: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.unsubscribe = this.firestoreRef.onSnapshot(this.getCollection);
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
      this.unsubscribe();
    }

    getCollection = (querySnapshot) => {
      const userArr = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((res) => {
        const { title, description, rating, reviews, bannerUrl } = res.data();
        const store = [];
        const card = {
          key: res.id,
          res,
          title,
          description,
          rating,
          bannerUrl,
          categories: [],
          reviews,
        };
        userArr.push(card);
        firestore()
        .collection('restaurants')
        .doc(res.id)
        .onSnapshot(documentSnapshot => {
              store.push(documentSnapshot.data());
              store.map((num) => {
                  card["categories"] = num.categories;
                  userArr.push(card);  
            })
        });
      });
      this.setState({
        userArr,
        isLoading: false,
    });
  
    }


    render() {
          if(this.state.isLoading){
            return(
              <View style={styles.preloader}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
              </View>
            )
          }    
          return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                {
                  this.state.userArr.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                      <Card
                        key={i}
                        itemData={item}
                        onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('CardItemDetails', {itemData: item})}
                      />
                    );
                  })
                }
            </ScrollView>
          );
    }
};

export default CardListScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingBottom: 22,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
   },
   preloader: {
     left: 0,
     right: 0,
     top: 0,
     bottom: 0,
     position: 'absolute',
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'center'
   }
});
```

Here is the second class:

```
import React, {useRef, Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  StatusBar,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import { ImageHeaderScrollView, TriggeringView } from 'react-native-image-header-scroll-view';

import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const MIN_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 90 : 55;
const MAX_HEIGHT = 350;

class CardItemDetails extends Component {
  
  render(props) {
    const itemData = props.itemData;
    const navTitleView = useRef(null);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        <ImageHeaderScrollView
          maxHeight={MAX_HEIGHT}
          minHeight={MIN_HEIGHT}
          maxOverlayOpacity={0.6}
          minOverlayOpacity={0.3}
          renderHeader={() => (
            <Image source={{uri: itemData.bannerUrl}} style={styles.image} />
          )}
          renderForeground={() => (
            <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.imageTitle}>{itemData.title}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          renderFixedForeground={() => (
            <Animatable.View style={styles.navTitleView} ref={navTitleView}>
              <Text style={styles.navTitle}>{itemData.title}</Text>
            </Animatable.View>
          )}>
          
          <TriggeringView
            style={styles.section}
            onHide={() => navTitleView.current.fadeInUp(200)}
            onDisplay={() => navTitleView.current.fadeOut(100)}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>Overview</Text>
              <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
                <FontAwesome name="star" size={16} color="#FF6347" />
                <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 2}}>{itemData.rating}</Text>
                <Text>({itemData.reviews})</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TriggeringView>
          <View style={[styles.section, styles.sectionLarge]}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionContent}>{itemData.description}</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.section}>
            <View style={styles.categories}>
              {itemData.categories.map((category, index) => (
                <View style={styles.categoryContainer} key={index}>
                  <FontAwesome name="tag" size={16} color="#fff" />
                  <Text style={styles.category}>{category}</Text>
                </View>
              ))}
            </View>
          </View>

          <View style={[styles.section, {height: 250}]}>
            {/*<MapView
              provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
              style={{flex: 1}}
              region={{
                latitude: Number(itemData.coordinate[0]),
                longitude: Number(itemData.coordinate[1]),
                latitudeDelta: 0.00864195044303443,
                longitudeDelta: 0.000142817690068,
              }}>
              <MapView.Marker
                coordinate={itemData.coordinate}
                image={require('../../assets/images/map_marker.png')}
              />
            </MapView>*/}
          </View>
        </ImageHeaderScrollView>
      </View>
    );
        }
};

export default CardItemDetails;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    height: MAX_HEIGHT,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  name: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  section: {
    padding: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  sectionContent: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'justify',
  },
  categories: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  categoryContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#FF6347',
    borderRadius: 20,
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
  },
  category: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#fff',
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  imageTitle: {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  navTitleView: {
    height: MIN_HEIGHT,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 5,
    opacity: 0,
  },
  navTitle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  sectionLarge: {
    minHeight: 300,
  },
});
```